# In Rails 5, is setup called each time test is run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

Let's say I have the code below in my model test.

```
def setup
  @object = Object.new(name: "test")
end

test "test 1" do
  @object.age = 25
  assert @object.valid?
end

test "test 1" do
  ...
end

...
```

Is the `setup` method called for before each `test` is done or it is just called once and proceeds to run all the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setup` method will be run before each test case. The [minitest documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/5.10.3/Minitest%2FTest%2FLifecycleHooks:setup) says:

> Runs before every test. Use this to set up before each test run.